# problem with interface with ip static in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface

On ubuntu 16.04, I had the interfaces file with the following information:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Public Interface (Static IP)
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
   address 192.168.88.13
   gateway 192.168.88.1 
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.88.255
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
   dns-search 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
   dns-domain 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# Local Network Interface (Static IP)
auto enp2s1
iface enp2s1 inet static
   address 192.168.0.10
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.0.255
   network 192.168.0.0
```

And work fine. Now update Ubuntu 18.04 and doesn't work enp2s0 (first interface public)

```
ifconfig

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        ether 94:18:82:0c:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 570  bytes 53571 (53.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 79  bytes 11201 (11.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16
```

Only work in dhcp:

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

What changed with the new version that does not accept the previous configuration? Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 does not use the legacy `/etc/network/interfaces`. See "[How to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)" for a brief tutorial.

Comment: sorry, but in "How to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 18.04" they explain that you can still use. And the enp2s1 interface works. Also, hide the procedure described (sudo ip a flush enp0s3 && sudo systemctl restart networking.service) and it works at the moment. Stop working when restarting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 does not use the legacy configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces`. Instead of the old `ifupdown` mechanism, Ubuntu 18.04 uses Netplan, as documented in the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Network_configuration). See "[How to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)" for a brief tutorial:

- For Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, use the graphical Settings tool:

  - Go to Network;
  - Press the gear button;
  - Select Manual configuration.
- For Ubuntu 18.04 Server, edit the [netplan](https://netplan.io/) configuration in `/etc/netplan`.

  - Most likely the configuration file is called `01-netcfg.yaml` for Ubuntu Server and `01-network-manager-all.yaml` for Ubuntu Desktop.
  - Netplan configuration files are written in [YAML](http://yaml.org/); take care not to insert any tabs.

Comment: your explanation is logical (and the post clarifies in part) but does not solve the problem raised in my question, since it only affects the interface enp2s0 and works well in the local interface enp2s1. If this configuration could no longer be used in /etc/network/interfaces then none should work. By the way, the file is called 01-network-manager-all.yaml

Comment: @user4839775: `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` is for *desktop* systems. On desktop systems you have a nice GUI.

Comment: Servers sometimes have a desktop (Gnome, Mate, etc) and, normally, no GUI is used to configure the interfaces

Comment: `netplan` is only used on **fresh installations**. Upgraded installations continue to use `ifupdown` or similar packages with `/etc/network/interfaces`. However, this appears to be not very well tested as I had an upgrade go "wrong" in that the `ifupdown` package got removed and I was left with a system that could not bring up the interfaces. Booting into a Ubuntu 18.04 CD and then chrooting into the actual system enabled me to install `ifupdown` which resolved the issue. This makes your answer *wrong* because the inquirer indicated that the system was upgraded from 16.04.

Comment: This will never be the solution. On a computer with four Ethernet interfaces, the processes you recommend are insufficient. The specified applications may not work on the new installed system. My cards are automatically closed at each system startup (except for the cards with DHCP enabled). I've had similar problems in almost all versions of Ubuntu, and I was able to remove the network manager to resolve it. @0xC0000022L comments is **TRUE**

Answer (score 1):

On a new installation of Ubuntu 18 server, you can use the same network configuration that you used on Ubuntu 16 server in /etc/network/interfaces, and it works, only you must:

1. `sudo apt install ifupdown`
2. edit the file /etc/network/interfaces
3. `cd /etc/netplan/` and then `mv 50-cloud-init.yaml 50-cloud-init.yaml.old`
4. DNS configuration:
   vi /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
   [Resolve]
   DNS=4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8
   or your DNS server ip

I guess it will also work on an update from Ubuntu 16 server to Ubuntu 18 server.